# Spring boot search filter and pagination

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to use pagination, filter and search in a single endpoint of a  RestController.
I am using spring 5. Can anyone suggest what will the best approach for this solution.

Comment: try to use something like jquery datatables. It help you do all these in one REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SearchFilter {
    private String searchValue;
    @Min(0)
    private int offset;
    @Min(1)
    private int limit;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/texts")
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Text>> search(@RequestBody @Valid SearchFilter filter) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("text").regex(Pattern.compile(filter.getSearchValue()).pattern(), "i"))
            .skip(filter.getOffset())
            .limit(filter.getLimit());
        ...
```

Regarding the pagination (kind of `limit` and `offset` above), you can use also `@RequestParam(required=false)` for the `pageSize` and `pageNumber`, and then do if possible `PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize)`.